# Date Tick-marks (mm/dd) on Slider

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have added a slider to my plot.

```
ax2 = fig.add_axes([.1, .01, .8, .05])
ax2_Slider = Slider(ax2, 'NormDate', valmin, valmax,  valstep=1, color='w', initcolor='none', track_color='g')
ax2_Slider.valtext.set_visible(False)
```

In matplotlib, the slider values must be float, not date.
Thus I used date2num to convert the dates values.

```
leftDate = datetime.date.today()  - relativedelta(days=366)
valmin = mpl.dates.date2num(leftDate)
valmax = mpl.dates.date2num(datetime.date.today())
```

How can I add tick marks to the slider to show mm/dd?
Also how to add title showing which date is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you could set tick labels. But why not also display the actual date?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
from datetime import date, timedelta
from matplotlib.dates import date2num, num2date

#set figure layout
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
gs = fig.add_gridspec(2, 3, width_ratios=[1, 10, 1], height_ratios=[10, 1])

#main panel
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, :])
#slider panel
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 1])
valmin = date2num(date.today()  - timedelta(days=366))
valmax = date2num(date.today())
ax2_Slider = Slider(ax2, 'NormDate', valmin, valmax,  valstep=1, color='w', initcolor='none', track_color='g')
#adding and formatting of the date ticks
ax2.add_artist(ax2.xaxis)
x_tick_nums=np.linspace(valmin, valmax, 10)
ax2.set_xticks(x_tick_nums, [num2date(s).strftime("%m-%d") for s in x_tick_nums])

#convert slider value to date
def changed_slider(s):
    ax2_Slider.valtext.set_text(num2date(s).date())
    #...
    #other things that should happen when the slider value changes 

#initiate the correct date display
changed_slider(valmin)
ax2_Slider.on_changed(changed_slider)

plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

Comment: Great research  --  as noted in you other post #adding and formatting of the date ticks
ax2.add_artist(ax2.xaxis)